# Do I need to install Apache and PHP/Java to develop Web Apps in Ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

In new Ubuntu tablet do we install apache server and program web application by using PHP or java?

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't want to run a webserver on the tablet.  You have two options here:

1) You can write a native HTML5 app, which runs only in a browser component and has no server-side backend.  You can learn more about native HTML5 apps here: http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tutorials/html5/

2) You can integrate your website with Ubuntu Unity using Webapps integration scripts.  Here all of your code lives on your own remote server, but it uses Javascript hooks to integrate with the Ubuntu Touch shell.  You can find out how to do that here: http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/javascript/unity-webapps/